Exercises like kegel and squats
I wanted to know as a women and unmarried that I want to lose some weight.  is doing kegel exercises which is basically effect on lower part of the body and squats is it permissible ?I will be doing the exercises at my home ? Is there any restrictions in Islam about it ? I couldn’t found any restrictions except yoga.
